# addClass to array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am comparing 2 arrays of numbers to find matches.

If a match is found I would like to color that element by assigning the css class.
Matching works but addClass is ignored. Just need class added to results.

**JavaScript**

```
var main = ["10", "13", "28", "35", "40"];
var picked = ["05", "13", "28", "35", "42"];
var matched = [];
for (var j = 0; j < main.length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < picked.length; k++) {
        var n = picked[k];
        if (main[j] == n) {
                matched.push(n);
                $("n").addClass("match");
                break;
                  }
        }
    }
$("#matches").append("<li>" + matched + "</li>");
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xgLLz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change ur

`$("n").addClass("match");`

to

```
$("ul").addClass("match");
```

It works fine now.

[WORKING SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xgLLz/2/)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xgLLz/1/)
Class are applied on html element not on string, so apply it on li

```
var main = ["10", "13", "28", "35", "40"];
var picked = ["05", "13", "28", "35", "42"];
var matched = [];
var li = '';
for (var j = 0; j < main.length; j++) {

    for (var k = 0; k < picked.length; k++) {
        var n = picked[k];
        if (main[j] == n) {
                matched.push(n);
            li += '<li class="match">' + n + '</li>';

                break;
                  }
        }
    }
$("#matches").append(li);
```